# Ignoring function calls from cProfile log

Tags: python, cprofile, pstats

I know that it is possible to get the frequency of function calls for a particular module using the `pstats.print_stats('python_script.py:')`, however I would like to print a report of the frequencies of all invoked functions in a profiled program that do not involve a set of functions.

For instance, say that I have `function1`, `function2`, `function3`, and `function4` (assume that this list is much larger) and that I want to print the number of times each function was invoked as long as it isn't `function3`.   Is it possible to create a list of the functions to be ignored and pass that to the `pstats` module as well as the file that I am profiling?

Particularly, I am interested in the number of calls for all functions that do not include the previously mentioned set.  I could probably write a script to parse out the full listing of functions and ignore that set, but I feel that there may be an easier way in the pstats module.